# How could a print statement removal break my project? (Swift/Xcode)

Tags: swift, printing

If I so much as comment out the print line, everything in toVC fails to load. Every element of toVC is nil. If I leave the print statement everything works as intended. Why?

I am in a `UITabBarControllerDelegate`'s `animationControllerForTransitionFrom` method if that helps anything.

I have never had anything like this happen before. As soon as I remove the line, it breaks the first time I touch any element attached with an `IBOutlet`. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
func animateToProfile(using transitionContext: UIViewControllerContextTransitioning) {
    guard let fromVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .from)?.childViewControllers.first,
        let toVC = transitionContext.viewController(forKey: .to)?.childViewControllers.first as? ProfileViewController,
        let superviewToAdd = toVC.parent?.view else { return }

    print("\(toVC.view.frame)")

    let sideMenuOriginX = UIScreen.main.bounds.width * (98 / 414)

    toVC.sideMenuView.frame.origin.x = toVC.view.frame.width
    toVC.visualEffectView.alpha = 0

    transitionContext.containerView.addSubview(superviewToAdd)

    let duration = transitionDuration(using: transitionContext)

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration, delay: 0, options: [.curveEaseInOut], animations: {
        toVC.sideMenuView.frame.origin.x = sideMenuOriginX
        toVC.visualEffectView.alpha = 1
    }, completion: { _ in
        transitionContext.completeTransition(!transitionContext.transitionWasCancelled)
    })
}
```

Comment: What happens if you replace your `print("\(toVC.view.frame)")` to `_ = toVC.view` ?

Comment: That fixes it. I figured it was a problem like that, but I have never had to do that with a transition before. Why would I have to here?

Comment: You can try `toVC.loadView()`. I'm not so good at how View Controllers are managed while transition, but in some cases iOS passes us a View Controller before `loadView()` is completed. And the first access to the `view` property implicitly invokes `loadView()` and it triggers `viewDidLoad()`, where usual VC is setup. So, when I find something similar to your issue, I try `_ = vc.view` or `vc.loadView()`.

Comment: It works, I just don't like having one circumstance where I have to do things out of over 10. I like symmetry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah. Views in UIViewControllers are loaded lazily, usually by the SDK at relevant parts of the lifecycle. Which is why you do set up code in `viewDidLoad` by which time the view has been loaded.

Because it is lazily loaded when you call `toVC.view` in the print statement you are causing it to load.

I suspect that this line `toVC.sideMenuView.frame.origin.x = toVC.view.frame.width` may be an issue. when you are setting some property of a view which is then being overwritten.

To attempt to debug this, try stepping into that line. Alternatively you could replace the `print` statement with a simple `_ = toVC.view` to force the view to load. Or, add some debugging statement of `print(toVC.isViewLoaded)` at various points in the code to see if the view is actually being loaded.

Comment: Would this be caused from the view controller that I am going to not having any code in viewDidLoad that involves its inner views?

Comment: Depends on how the inner views are created and added.